# How to program multiplayer elements into a visual basic 2010 Game

Tags: vb.net

I just finished programming turn and card logic to the visual basic Game I'm design.

Initially I the user at start up can pick the game size whether it is 2, 3, 4, or a 5 player game.

So I choose 5 player game. When I choose 5 players cards from my deckarray are loaded into each players card array. When they play their card(s) their cards are subtracted from their arrays to the discard array. When deckarray is full, the discard array becomes the new deck, by loading its values into the deck array and turning its values to 0.

Currently each players turn is determined by a Value of a variable I call "T". When a player finishes his turn, then the application screens changes all the check boxes representing the cards into represent the values of the next player's cards. So in essence currently all players share the same form, and are only accessed 1 computer.

Getting down to what I'm asking, how do I implement network code into the program to allow for multiple computers on a network to connect and share the game session, to where when T changes its value, the next player gains control of the screen on "their" computer. For now I'm not going to worry about all the players sharing the same form and seeing the other players cards when it is a respective players turn, I just want to get started on the networking portion.

Currently I'm using visual basic 2010. I've searched for tutorials with no luck.

Hope my question isn't too broad... It is hard to narrow the question concerning a multiplayer game concerning networking.

Comment: Some code usually makes this whole process go a lot faster. Also, why not try and read some tutorials like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx). If you don't get it, come back to us with a specific problem.

Comment: I think this question needs to be more specific but it will be better handled, even when rewritten, here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would look into using WCF to create a service that can raise events to the clients.

Comment: You're going to have to first get used to thinking about it in client / server terms. The server probably knows all the information, and a client only has a subset view of that information that is specific to that client. Think about your game / program in terms of messages that these different views might exchange (like, "it is now player 3's turn").

Comment: `how do I implement network code into the program to allow for multiple computers on a network` My first thought - get a book on networking with VB.NET and go through that. See if you come up with the next step then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've built your application in the wrong order (single user moving to multi user). But don't worry, Microsoft did this with DOS and Windows, so you're in good company.

I would suggest starting from scratch and designing your software from the ground up to be multi user.

The simplest approach would probably be to use a very small database and use queries to get and set the state of the game.

Each computer would be a 'client' and one of them would also be a 'server' and hold the database.

Comment: I've been debating doing that. As when I finished the basic mechanics I'm constantly looking back at things I could have done better. I started programming this game to really help me understand visual basic, so everything was new to me, and I have learned a lot about the language designing this. Many portions of my game really represent my many different phases of knowledge I had at the time of programming the game. I will start by writing down my persudo code, and thinking how to implement everything into a database. Then see how databases will talk and update a users screen.

Comment: I started it fresh, instead of Arrays, I loaded all my card names, number, quantities, damage amount, and card types into an SQL table.